# Elegant way to turn a Vector3 into Vector4

Tags: rust, rust-crates, nalgebra

This may be a silly question, but is there a way to move between different types inside the nalgebra crate without having to recur to using the `new()` method each time, I found that going from a `Vector4` to a `vector3` can be done with the `.xyz` method. but after scrolling in the documentation i didn't found what I was looking for.

I was expecting something like
Is there something that works like this

```
let holder = Vector3::new(1,1,1);
let new_holder = Vector4::from((holder, 2));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`push()`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/latest/nalgebra/base/type.Vector.html#method.push):

```rust
use nalgebra::Vector3;

fn main() {
    let src = Vector3::new(1, 2, 3);
    let dst = src.push(4);
    println!("{dst:?}");
}
```